# How do I add a weight (or prefilter) for a phrase suggester?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am new to phrase suggester and have been reading the docs. The completion suggester has a way to add a weight so that the results are scored. The phrase suggester has no such option unless I am missing. I have:

```
POST test/_search
{
  "suggest": {
    "text": "noble prize",
    "simple_phrase": {
      "phrase": {
        "field": "title.trigram",
        "size": 1,
        "gram_size": 3,
        "direct_generator": [ {
          "field": "title.trigram",
          "suggest_mode": "always"
        } ],
        "highlight": {
          "pre_tag": "<em>",
          "post_tag": "</em>"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to make some of the suggestions more/less important and/or exclude some. Image the above comes back with "nobel prize" but I want to exclude that suggestion or manually weight it as less important. Is that possible?

The example comes directly from the first example [found here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-phrase.html)

EDIT
Since all phrases passed in by my users are saved in elasticsearch the above code will not suggest a better phrase. For instance if "noble prize" and "nobel prize" are both in the index and user types "noble prize" I want to suggest "nobel prize" but it won't. Most user types in nobel prize correctly so I can increment each time a query is used and therefore suggest the correct one. Make sense good.

Another Edit: it's weird that they assume your index won't grow and that you don't want to prioritize phrases like the completion suggester allows you to do.

A complete example:

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "trigram": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": ["standard", "shingle"]
          },
          "reverse": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": ["standard", "reverse"]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "shingle": {
            "type": "shingle",
            "min_shingle_size": 2,
            "max_shingle_size": 3
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "trigram": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "trigram"
            },
            "reverse": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "reverse"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
POST test/test
{"title": "noble prize", "weight": 1}
POST test/test
{"title": "nobel prize", "weight": 2}
```

Query:

```
GET /test/_search
{
   "suggest": {
      "text": "noble prize",
      "simple_phrase": {
         "phrase": {
            "field": "title.trigram",
            "size": 1,
            "gram_size": 3,
            "direct_generator": [
               {
                  "field": "title.trigram",
                  "suggest_mode": "always"
               }
            ],
             "collate": {
               "query": {
                  "inline": {
                     "match": {
                        "title": "{{suggestion}}"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "prune": true
            },
            "highlight": {
               "pre_tag": "<em>",
               "post_tag": "</em>"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Results in (wrongly) "noble prize":

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "suggest": {
    "simple_phrase": [
      {
        "text": "noble prize",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 11,
        "options": []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Things are not clear for me, as I'm trying to understand the use case. You say `if "noble prize" and "nobel prize" are both in the index and user types "noble prize" I want to suggest "nobel prize"`. How do you want Elasticsearch to choose between `nobel` and `noble`? ES doesn't who Alfred Nobel was. You need to give ES a _hint_.

Comment: Then you say `Most user types in nobel prize correctly so I can increment each time a query is used and therefore suggest the correct one`. Is this the _hint_ I mentioned earlier? How do you tell ES that `nobel` has been asked for more times than `noble` and thus it is the more correct one?

Comment: I've tried to reproduce this case and what I think he's saying is that if both `noble prize` and `nobel prize` have been indexed, then when the user searches for `nobel prize` then both `noble prize` and `nobel prize` come up in the suggestions, while if he inputs `noble prize` then only `noble prize` comes up. I think he'd like `nodel prize` to also show up.

Comment: @AndreiStefan - Don't get bogged down on the details of how to increment or weight it. All I need is a way to score the results as the completion suggester does.

Comment: I'm trying to help you, but if you don't provide answers to my questions that would be hard to do. The suggesters are different and saying you want one to score like the other one is not going to help much. With Elasticsearch most of the times users start with a fixed idea in mind and if that one doesn't work they still think that area needs a fix. But sometimes it's better to think at the issue from a different angle. And this is what I was trying to achieve by asking you those questions.

Comment: As you saw both myself and @Val are confused on what doesn't work. If you can clarify both our assumptions it would probably move forward your issue.

Comment: Now I saw your edit. I do not agree with your statement that ES returns `(wrongly) "noble prize"`. `noble prize` is one of the documents in the index and it matches perfectly. Also, in case of a solution that will fix the typos, this case still won't work: `noble` is a valid English word. Given that you provided this example and stated that `noble prize` is wrong suggests that you want to provide suggestions on frequently searched terms, meaning my assumption above. Please, clarify, and address my previous questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which functionality you want to implement? `Did You Mean` or `Autocomplete`? In the case I can give other suggestions to you.

To Prune your suggestion result you can use `collate` like this:

```
{
   "suggest": {
      "text": "iphon",
      "simple_phrase": {
         "phrase": {
            "field": "title.trigram",
            "size": 1,
            "gram_size": 3,
            "direct_generator": [
               {
                  "field": "title.trigram",
                  "suggest_mode": "always"
               }
            ],
             "collate": {
               "query": {
                  "inline": {
                     "match": {
                        "title": "{{suggestion}}"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "prune": true
            },
            "highlight": {
               "pre_tag": "<em>",
               "post_tag": "</em>"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In the result you will have a `"collate_match": true/false` which indicates if any suggestion is matched your collate query.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a complete example. I have set the weight of "nobel prize" to 2 and "noble prize" to 1. With your answer I wrongly get "noble prize". I don't see a "collate_match" in the results

Comment: I will close this question....you answered the question but I asked a bad question and will rephrase it in another question. thanks you and sorry for confuse.