# How to filter elastic search term or phrase suggester by a specific field?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm using elastic search 5.3 and to provide did-you-mean functionality, I want to limit the context of term or phrase suggester to *only user's documents* not all the documents in the index. here's my current `_search` query body using term suggester (which returns suggestion based on all indexed documents):

```
{
    "suggest": {
        "text": "docyment",
        "title_correction: {
            "term": {
                "size": 2,
                "prefix_length": 3,
                "field": "title",
                "analyzer": "standard",
                "min_doc_freq": 1,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can see that filtering was part of `phrase_suggester` in the past ([check this issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/3482)) but it seems that it has been deprecated and replaced by context suggester (only for completion fields though), so it's not suitable for my case.

What I need is to have a filter like: `"filter": {"term": {"user_id": 12345}}`  so suggestions will be based on user's documents.

I would appreciate it if anyone could come up with answers to my questions :

0- Why the filter has been deprecated from phrase suggester? only to boost up performance?

1- If it has been replaced by something else and there's recommended way to do it, so I can solve my issue?

(I've asked same question in [elastic forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-filter-limit-term-or-phrase-suggester-by-a-specific-field/99215), and will update both of these questions in case I find the answer)

Comment: I didn't understand why the context suggester isn't suitable. It seems like the context suggested is a decorated suggester, isn't it ?

Comment: @aclokay if I got it right, context suggester works only on completion fields (which will be kept as a graph in memory) and is not the right choice to implement spell checking as described here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html : `[completion suggester] is not meant for spell correction or did-you-mean functionality like the term or phrase suggesters.`
So I need to limit either term or phrase suggester to user's documents.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same need basically, there is the prune query which should allow to rule out the documents you don't want: have a look at [How do I add a weight (or prefilter) for a phrase suggester?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43944467/how-do-i-add-a-weight-or-prefilter-for-a-phrase-suggester?rq=1)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)